# What is the cleaner status code and response body for resource to update/delete is not found?

Tags: rest, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

This is how my app sends responses.

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "messages": [
        "Blog have not been found"
    ]
}
```

Any alternative or better approach?

Answer (score 0):

**404** is the correct status code

> **404 - NotFound**: The requested resource could not be found [...]